# iOS: Auto-Sync in background with core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am developing a auto-sync application with offline functionality. User will be creating folder and documents and can sync with the server. There is a functionality of auto-sync in which sync with the server will happen in background every hour. During the sync process, user can also create, delete folders/document. All the changes are saved in core data. For changes to be send to server, i am maintaining a bool. If bool is NO then send those items to server and once response received set the bool to YES.

Now my problem is how can i make sure that changes done while sync is in process to be sent to server. Since sync is in process and during this if i make any changes to item which has been sent to server, even though sync bool is set to NO changes from server is update to YES again and these changes will not be send to server.

Note: I doesn't want to make any restrict to user while sync is in process.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: It’s bad idea to add special attribute for this purpose. You should store change set somewhere else. Also, I recommend You to use [Ensembles](http://www.ensembles.io) for syncing.

Comment: Why would you store special attributes outside the database? You lose save atomicity that way, risk breakage between the two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll tell you how we specifically solved this. In our syncing code, any attribute on any given object which a user can change also has an associated 'dirty flag', simply an additional boolean which is set whenever the user changes a property on an object in the main thread context (name has nameDirty, etc.). This boolean is automatically set based on a context pre-save notification observer, which checks the change dictionary of the context and marks attributes dirty as appropriate.

Sounds similar to your sync flag so far, though yours is per-object rather than per-attribute.

Any changes from the server will NOT be parsed into any attribute which has the dirty flag set to YES. Similarly, whenever a change is synced to the server, that flag is reset to NO so it will accept changes from the server again.

What happens when the user makes a change on the main context and the server parses in a change on the sync context (on a background thread) at the same time? That's where using the correct NSMergePolicy comes in. The main context has a merge policy telling its in-memory changes to trump anything in the database. Similarly, the sync context has a merge policy telling it to let any values in the database trump any in-memory changes in the sync context. (The same pre-save hook also pokes the sync context and tells it to sync any new changes to the server in the background.) This ensures the syncing process can never step on any changes the user just made on the main thread, even in a SQLite-level merge conflict.

The key here is the context separation between the context which takes user changes and the context which parses in server changes, as that allows us to very cleanly prioritize things and ensure bad merges can never happen. Both contexts are tied directly to the persistent store coordinator.

I'm working on a blog post about how our syncing framework works, but it's not quite done, so I don't have a link yet.

I know there are various third-party syncing libraries out there, and due to our unique requirements we chose to write our own, but I would definitely suggest seeing if any fit your needs out of the box.

Comment: Have you completed your blog. Please Share the link if so.