# iOS REST App - best practice for handling http requests(syncing data with server)

Tags: ios, rest, design-patterns, core-data

I'm iOS very fresh beginner..

I'm trying to build REST app that gets and updates data from/to some server (by http get and post requests using JSON data format).

I need to have some local saving mechanism (like Core Data) so that app can be used offline, but as soon as network is available it has to be synced (sent, refreshed) with server.

There will be lots of different requests on server, so there could be a lot of networking & json parsing code.
I would like to avoid having  viewController classes overloaded with lots of json parsing code.

My question is - what is the best practice on iOS to accomplish this?

Should I have one apiCommunicator with all requests (using NSUrlConnection) (and use delegating ui-updates to viewController that has requested data)?

Or should I have api calls in different classes (one per one model class)?

What is standard approach?

Can you at least point me to some readings or sample projects where I can learn more about.

If possible, I would like to see/read some solution without using 3rd apis, since I'm already overloaded with lot's of new stuff within iOS itself :)

Comment: I'm working on a blog post to discuss what we ended up with, but our app uses an in-house asynchronous generic object graph syncing system built on Core Data, which communicates with our similarly generic REST-like object API. Here's a comment I made explaining a few aspects of it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27532392/131779 Hopefully it's helpful reading material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all consider MVC when developing for iOS (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).

My personal preference is having a model class which communicates with your API and reports the results via a delegate (or block or notification, depending on many factors (http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/)). This class could be singleton as your app will probably need to constantly talk with your server and you want a single always-alive object handling your requests.

So the overview would look like this:

- Your views ask their controllers to do something (usually high level methods).
- Your controller layer will translate your view requests and perform an appropriate task (one of which may be an API call).
- Your controller will ask the model to perform an api method (say a GET).
- It will receive the result upon completion from your model (maybe map the JSON results to an object) and then hand it down to views which may need to reflect something in the UI.

For your model class you can use `NSUrlConnection` for simple api calls. But as you said you will need JSON parsing (and maybe an object mapping). For that matter a framework like `AFNetworking` (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) would ease your life a lot (although you can do all that using classes in cocoa).

Answer (score 1):

Just implement AFNetworking to your project and read the documentation. This would be helpful - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking